# installing ray using wheel in conda env

Tags: conda, ray

I am installing ray using a wheel.  In the conda yml file, under dependencies I have specified

```
  - ray-1.4.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

`conda env create` and `source activate ...`  work just fine.  When I try to import `ray` I get the following message

```
/home/.../.conda/envs/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/cli_logger.py:61: FutureWarning: Not all Ray CLI dependencies were found. In Ray 1.4+, the Ray CLI, autoscaler, and dashboard will only be usable via `pip install 'ray[default]'`. Please update your install command.
  "update your install command.", FutureWarning)
```

How should I update my install command?

Comment: Do you have to install using a wheel?

Comment: I'd prefer that.  The version of `ray` with `conda` is 1.3.

Comment: Any chance you can use pip to install the package instead? Conda doesn't support python wheel extras.

Comment: As a last step after the env is created, I have started to run `pip install ray-1.4.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl[default]`.  I was hoping to avoid that!

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. There is a conda package on conda-forge called ray-core. see [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ray-core). The version is currently at `1.4.0`, so you could simply add `conda-forge` to your channels and then specify `ray-core` to get ray. I just tested it and `conda` manages to install all dependencies correctly.
2. Looking more in-depth into the error, it seems like `ray` is trying to import the `colorful` module in that part of the code, see [here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/3a09c82fbfce8f00533234844729e6d99fb0f24c/python/ray/autoscaler/_private/cli_logger.py#L54). This is also available from `conda-forge`, so if you want to stick with the whl file strictly, I suggest to add the `colorful` module to your yml file